# Confusion about whether or not this matrix is onto/1-1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a beginner at matrices and I am trying to find out whether or not the linear transformation defined by the matrix $A$ is onto, and also whether it is 1-1.

Here is the matrix $A$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 &  3 &  4 & -1 &  2\\
    2 &  6 &  6 &  0 & -3\\
    3 &  9 &  3 &  6 & -3\\
    3 &  9 &  0 &  9 &  0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I reduced it to echeleon row form but I am not sure what to do from there, thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the reduced matrix have a zero column, then it is not 1-1 because for example $A(00001)^{T}$ will be zero, this will be the case, beacuse the matrix $A$ that a vector in $\mathbb{R}^5$ to $\mathbb{R}^4$, so it can´t be 1-1.
To see if it is into, you have to see that the columns generate $\mathbb{R}^4$, so if the reduced matrix have $4$ non-zero rows, that will be the case.

Comment: i see... thanks for the answer, one more question, is it possible for a matrix to be NOT be one to one AND NOT be onto??

Comment: You mean, a matrix that is not onto and not 1-1? yes, for example the matrix $0$ (is a trivial example, but i think you can find more easily, if not, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Seen as an operator, your matrix is a map from $\,5-$dimensional space to a $\,4-$dimensional one, so $\;1-1\;$ it certainly cannot be.

Now, if its rank is $\,4\,$ then it is onto (why?), so you really have to reduce it and check this...